# Is it possible to connect 2 git repositories?

Tags: git, repository

Let's say I have repository A and B.
I want to connect those two, so If I get back to a specific version of the files in, let's say, A that the connected version of B is automatically restored.

Or is it better to just put everything in one repository.

Comment: "Or is it better to just put everything in one repository." - probably yes, but it would help if you could explain _why_ you want to keep two different remotes in sync

Comment: If the dependency is strong, maybe all in one repository. Otherwise, look at the submodules: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules